# rename not supporting multi-byte characters

Tags: php, rename, multibyte

If I write:

```
rename('php109.tmp','test.jpg');
```

then it's fine and working.

but if I change it into:

```
rename('php109.tmp','中文.jpg');
```

it'll report

> "No such file or directory...".

But if the multi-byte characters can be written into database then can be read out, then why it fails when it is renamed ?

Comment: does your operating system or filesystem support multi-byte filenames?

Comment: yes,
and here is more information:
it's handled when submitting from web page,
page encoding is utf8
db encoding is utf8.
and i dumped the string only to find it's also utf8

Comment: What OS are you using? I've tested this on FreeBSD 4.11, Debian 5.0, and OS X 10.6.2, with no errors.

If you're using an OS with some sort of syscall trace facility, can you try enabling that?

Answer (score 0):

File systems do not necessarily use UTF-8. For instance, this is what Wikipedia says about [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfs):

> NTFS allows any sequence of 16-bit
>   values for name encoding (file names,
>   stream names, index names, etc.). This
>   means UTF-16 codepoints are supported,
>   but the file system does not check
>   whether a sequence is valid UTF-16 (it
>   allows any sequence of short values,
>   not restricted to those in the Unicode
>   standard).

You might need to use [iconv()](http://www.php.net/iconv) to convert between charsets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing a `setlocale(LC_ALL, array("es_ES.utf-8","es_ES@euro",'es_ES'));` or whatever your country code is, to make sure the locale is set correctly?

If this call does not return something with 'utf-8' in it, it means it failed and will then return the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

This Sample Should Helps , You Should Find Your Language Code Page And Replace With That. I Test Bellow Code And It Works In Windows For Arabic/Persian Names:

```
$newname = iconv("utf-8", "cp1256","گچپژ");
echo rename("1.txt", $newname);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost sure that the mbstring has nothing to do with this specific problem, I think the problem here relies on the encoding of your .php file.

Try changing the encoding of the file to UTF-8 (no BOM!) in your code editor.