# PHP filename encoding conversion issue

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to batch rename files in a folder with PHP. It's mostly working, though I'm having problems with accented characters.

An example of a filename with accented characters is `ÅRE_GRÖN.JPG`.

I would like to rename that file to `ARE_GRON.JPG`.

If I read the files in like this:

```
<?php
$path = __DIR__;
$dir_handle = opendir($path);

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    echo $file . "\n";
}

closedir($dir_handle);
```

...And the page displays `AÌŠRE_GROÌˆN.JPG`.

If I add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` to the beginning of my script, it displays the correct file name, but the `rename()` function seems to have no effect either way.

Here's what I've tried:

```
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    rename($file, str_replace('OÌˆ', 'O', $file)); # No effect
    rename($file, str_replace('Ö', 'O', $file)); # No effect
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

Do say if you believe I'm using the wrong tool for the job. If anyone knows how to achieve this with a Bash script, show me. I have no Bash chops.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Is your PHP script encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Since he said bash, I would guess he is referring to bash(1) which would suggest Lunix.

Comment: This is what I could find: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39660
However I believe there should already be a work-around for this, like using the encoding system PHP is okay with. I'll post an answer if I ever find anything.

Also possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873853/rename-not-supporting-multi-byte-characters

Comment: It could easily be Bash on cygwin, natively on Windows or on FreeBSD.

Comment: Sorry guys, OSX. I'm using Coda, and the encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Instead of `opendir()` and `readdir()`, have you tried `glob()`?  I have to wonder if it handles multibyte strings differently.  I haven't ever had need to find out for myself.

Comment: I tried `foreach (glob("*.JPG") as $filename) echo $filename;` and every occurrence of `Ö` still appears as `OÌˆ`.

Comment: I ran into a problem very similar to this yesterday and I couldn't figure out a very automated way to handle it. PHP just doesn't handle unicode properly. Fortunately, my case was isolated enough that I could use an extremely dirty hack to get around it using preg_replace but I knew exactly what I was looking for and where the unicode character would be in the string whereas your situation is random. I'm anxiously awaiting if anyone has a great solution for you.

Comment: @mkaatman Figured it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

I first ran `urlencode()` on the filename. This converts the string:

```
MÖRKGRÅ.JPG
```

To the URL friendly:

```
MO%CC%88RKGRA%CC%8A.JPG
```

I then ran `str_replace()` on the URL-encoded string, providing needles and haystacks in arrays. I only needed it for a few Swedish characters, so my solution looked like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$path = __DIR__;

$dir_handle = opendir($path);

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    $search = array('A%CC%8A', 'A%CC%88', 'O%CC%88');
    $replace = array('A', 'A', 'O');
    rename($file, str_replace($search, $replace, urlencode($file)));
}

closedir($dir_handle);
```

Job done :)

---

I've come to realise this is more versatile than I anticipated. Running another script, `url_encode()` gave me some slightly different output, but it's easy to change accordingly.

```
$search = array('%26Aring%3B', '%26Auml%3B', '%26Ouml%3B', '+');
$replace = array('A', 'A', 'O', '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of characters you want to replace, you can do it with

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//Ö/O/}" 2> /dev/null; done
```

On GNU you could more generally use

```
expr=""
for char in {A..Z}
do 
    expr+="s/[[=$char=]]/$char/g; "; 
done; 

for f in *; do 
    mv "$f" "$(sed -e "$expr" <<< "$f")" 2> /dev/null; 
done
```

to replace all A-like accented characters with an ascii A, for every character in the alphabet, but with no guarantees for OS X sed. Beware that this has the side effect of capitalizing all filenames.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried running that first script from the directory that holds the files, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try copy-pasting the Ö character from the filename rather than typing it. Unicode has a lot of pretty identical Ö characters.